# Fetching data from two api simultaneously in android asynch task

Tags: java, android, api

I am new to android and I have to implement two api's. I want to fetch data from one api that contains images, description and rating. And in other api I have genres i.e horror, thriller etc. My first api should run 1 time and other one should run that much time until all movies of that first api finished.(second api each time run with diff movie id)
My requirement is after fetching movie id from first url I need to insert that movie id in another url and fetch genres from that. I am not getting the approach for that.

Comment: Please read this **[ask]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use below approach

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Show progress loader to user
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
        //Logic to call 1st API - This is HTTP call
        String MovieId = fetchMovieDetails();

        //Pass above MovieId in next API call - This is also HTTP call
        JSONObject jsonObject = fetchGenres(MovieId);

        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
        //Parse this jsonObject and process further
    }
}
```